# Prove that every year contains at least $4$ months and at most $5$ months with $5$ Sundays

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> Prove that every year contains at least $4$ months and at most $5$ months with $5$ Sundays each.

Miklos Bona rates this question as "less difficult than average" while I am stuck on it although I am able to solve most of the "average" exercises in his book.

I tried as follows:

> There are $52$ weeks and $1$ day in a year, hence at least $52$ Sundays and at most $53$ Sundays. Let us group these Sundays into blocks of $5$ Sundays in each group, so we find that we can find $10$ complete "$5-Sunday$" blocks. We want to show that there are at least $4$ and at most $5$ months containing one such block each.

I understand that somehow I have to use the fact that a month can have $5$ Sundays only if the last Sunday comes on date $29,30$ or $31$. But I am not able to proceed further. Please provide some hint only and NOT a complete solution.

EDIT: Based on the hints, I have realized a solution (turns out I was necessarily complicating matters):

> It is enough to show that there cannot be $3$ months or $6$ months having $5$ Sundays. The other cases are similar.
>
> First we show that there cannot be $\leq3$ months having $5$ Sundays. Let the contrary happen i.e. let $n$ be the no. of such months, with $0\leq n\leq 3$. We note that every month has at least $4$ Sundays (the key point here, which I had missed) and that there are at least $52$ and at most $53$ Sundays in a year.
>
> As $n$ months have $5$ Sundays each, a total of $5n$ Sundays are blocked and hence there are at least $52-2n$ and at most $53-5n$ Sundays to be distributed among $12-n$ months. Each such month has exactly $4$ Sundays so total no. of Sundays in the year$=4(12-n)+5n=48+n$ with $0\leq n\leq 3$. Hence the maximum no. of Sundays is $48+3=51$ while there are $52$ Sundays in a year, at least, which is a contradiction. So, $n\geq4$.
>
> Let $n\geq6$ then no. of Sundays blocked by these "special" months = $5n$. So total no. of Sundays in the year $=48+n$ with $n\geq6$ so total no. of Sundays is at least $54$, again a contradiction as total no. of Sundays is at most $53$. Hence $n\leq5$.

Comment: Hint: look at the months by  3 for one case, by 2 for the other case.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "months by 2 and 3". Do you mean months modulo 2 and modulo 3, or something else?

Comment: No, pack succeding months by groups of 2 or 3.

Comment: Your line of reasoning is way too complicated. Each month has at least $4$ sundays. Some months have $5$ sundays. Now if a year has $52$ sundays, the only computation we have to do is: $52 - 12*4 = 52 - 48 = 4$. So there are $4$ months with $5$ sundays. Similar calculation for a year with $53$ sundays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every month contains $\geq28$ days hence at least $4$ sundays.

If the number of months containing $5$ sundays exceeds $5$ then what can be said about the total number of sundays in a year?

Comment: If the no. of months containing $5$ Sundays is $\geq6$ then the total no. of such Sundays $\geq30$. But there are $52$ or $53$ Sundays in a year hence other months can have $\leq 22$ or $23$ Sundays...not really sure if I am going anywhere.

Comment: Ah, so we consider cases now: Let us consider that there are $6$ months having $5$ Sundays so the remaining no. of Sundays $=23$ at the most. There are $6$ months remaining each has at least $4$ Sundays so there should be at least $24$ remaining Sundays while we have $23$ remaining Sundays at the most. Hence a contradiction. Similarly for $n=7,8,...,12$

Comment: Yes, in short: if $5$ sundays in at least $6$ months then at least $6\times5+6\times4=54$ sundays in a whole year.

Comment: See my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Going along with your train of thought,

HINT: how many Sundays must each month have?

HINT: distribute the Sundays (minimally) to each month using the previous hint. What happens to the rest of the Sundays?

This will have to use a variant of Pigeon-hole.

Comment: Is it possible to find out how the Sundays are distributed in any arbitrary year?

Comment: Yes, there are more complicated formulas for that. But you don't need to do that in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok once I try your method I will inform.

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

1. As you say, every year has 52 or 53 Sundays.
2. Every month has 4 or 5 Sundays.
3. Every year has exactly 12 months.

That is all the information you need to prove the assertion. You don't need to worry about 29's, 30's and 31's.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please see my edited question.